# Sheets or Excel Formula for YOY% Change

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Say I have the following table, and I want to calculate YOY% Change.
How would I do this in Excel or Google Sheets, if they are not placed in the same row?

```
Date   Sessions  YOY% Change
4/1/2016  300
5/1/2016  400
6/1/2017  500
5/1/2017  20000      ?  (Answer would be) 20,000/400-1
4/1/2017  10000      ?  (Anwswer would be) 10,000/300-1
```

Comment: Here is what the table should look like. Seems like when I typed this question through, the table didn't format properly. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qJm5WFwu1iJiNVof-mZOcDnLa0QNqtXHt7okgPsvUs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy/drag down:

```
=IFERROR(B2/INDEX($B$1:B1,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),$A$1:A1,0))-1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect Thank you!

Comment: @Inaya after the question is 15 minutes old you can select this as the correct answer by clicking the check mark by the answer.  Please do so as it will mark the question as answered and remove it from the unanswered queue.